# Calculation Proportion in R with Loop?

Tags: r

I have a similar dataset to this:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Person= c("John Smith", "John Smith", "John Smith", 
"John Smith", "John Smith", "John Smith", "John Smith", "Martin Harris", 
"Martin Harris", "Martin Harris", "Kyle Short"), Item.Order = c("ABC", 
"ABC", "DEF", "ABC", "IJK", "ABC", "DEF", "IJK", "ABC", "ABC", 
"DEF"), Status = c("R", "W", "R", "R", 
"W", "W", "W", "R", "W", "R", 
"W")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

I want to calculate how much stuff (`Stuff.Order`) each person wasted as a function of how many events they performed.

For example, we see that `John Smith` performed 7 events. Out of these 7 events, he wasted items 4 times. So this calculation should be 4/7=0.5714286.

I want to create a loop that does this for each person (find out how many items each person wasted per how many events total they performed).

Thanks!

Comment: `prop.table(table(df[-2]),1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this without a loop i.e. grouped by 'Surgeon', get the `mean` of logical vector (`Status == "Wasted"`)

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df %>% 
   group_by(Surgeon) %>% 
   summarise(Prop = mean(Status == "Wasted"))
```

-output

```
out
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Surgeon        Prop
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 John Smith    0.571
2 Kyle Short    1    
3 Martin Harris 0.333
```

If we need a bar plot

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(out, aes(x = Surgeon, y = Prop)) + geom_col()
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
barplot(proportions(table(df[-2]), 1)[,2])
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to also find the mean for "returned" in the same function

Comment: @Tiffany you can change the code to `df %>% 
   group_by(Surgeon) %>%summarise(PropWast = mean(Status == "Wasted"), PropRet = mean(Status == "Returned"))`

Comment: @Tiffany or in base R, instead of subsettting `barplot(proportions(table(df[-2]), 1))`